# customize the style of javafx datepicker

Tags: css, javafx, datepicker, locale

I am trying to avoid rolling my own JavaFX control if I could do this with either CSS or some code in main.java/controller.java.

There is a button within the datepicker, which shows a calander icon, I want to change it to display an image.
I could do this to button using `-fx-graphic`. Is there an equivalent in datepicker?

I also wants to know if the weekday could be modified. my Locale is Chinese, it shows "星期一","星期二" and so on. It is like "Weekday Monday", which is long and unnecessary. I want to change it to 一, 二, etc. It is equivalent to Mon, Tue, etc.

Is there anyway to do this? if CSS could not do it. 
Could this be done using reflection and set string value?

Comment: have a look here about setting your Locale : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383203/changing-the-language-in-javafx-8-datepicker

Also to check about the CSS attributes of the DatePicker have a look at modena.css on line 2977 and below and i hope you will find something useful to change the Image/shape : https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470

Comment: The Locale workaround is interesting, but I still want the month name in Chinese. modena.css could possibly solve the icon issue, I will dig into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing a bit with the date picker component I have found out how to change the icon, using only css, in the button next to the date picker... **it's more of a hack**, but I could not google anywhere the "*official way*".

```
.date-picker:editable > .arrow-button > * {
    -fx-opacity: 0; /* Set the node in the button to be visible */
}

.date-picker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-image: url("/icons/calendar.png"); /* Url of the icon */
    -fx-background-size: 60% 60%; /* Can be `cover` or `100% 100%` ect. */
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center; /* Put the icon in the center */
}
```

With more styles I have managed to make my date picker look like this, notice the custom icon:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Formatting/configuring the internals of picker's dropDown is done in DatePickerContent. Which unfortunately is an internal class (no idea why it didn't make it into public api, fx9 would have been a perfect time to move it out into the open, along with the skins).

DatePickerContent configures the text of the weekDayName cells in a method `updateDayNameCells()` which internally is called whenever they need to be re-configured. If you are allowed to access/tweak internal code internals:

- extend DatePickerContent to override updateDayNameCells, fully re-implement (c&p ;) and use your own formatter (the example below uses the "narrow standalone" style). Access to the dayNameCells and other fields must be done reflectively (beware: dirty!)
- extend DatePickerSkin and inject your custom content, again requires reflective access (beware: dirty!)
- extend DatePicker and let it return the custom skin in its skin factory method

Sample code:

```
public class DatePickerConfig extends Application {

    /**
     * Custom picker content which allows to tweak the formatter for weekDay cells.
     */
    public static class XDatePickerContent extends DatePickerContent {

        private DateTimeFormatter weekDayNameFormatter;

        public XDatePickerContent(DatePicker datePicker) {
            super(datePicker);
        }

        /**
         * c&p from super to format with narrow formatter
         */
        @Override
        public void updateDayNameCells() {
            // first day of week, 1 = monday, 7 = sunday
            Locale locale = getLocale();
            int firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek().getValue();

            List<DateCell> dayNameCells = getDayNameCells();
            int daysPerWeek = getDaysPerWeek();
            // july 13th 2009 is a Monday, so a firstDayOfWeek=1 must come out of the 13th
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2009, 7, 12 + firstDayOfWeek);
            DateTimeFormatter weekDayNameFormatter = getWeekDayNameFormatter();
            for (int i = 0; i < daysPerWeek; i++) {
                String name = weekDayNameFormatter.withLocale(locale).format(date.plus(i, DAYS));
                dayNameCells.get(i).setText(getTitleCaseWord(name));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Lazily creates and returns the formatter for week days.
         * Note: this is called from the constructor which implies that
         * the field is not available.
         */
        private DateTimeFormatter getWeekDayNameFormatter() {
            if (weekDayNameFormatter == null) {
                weekDayNameFormatter =
                        createWeekDayNameFormatter(); // 
            }
            return weekDayNameFormatter;
        }

        /**
         * Factory method for weekDayNameFormatter, here: narrow standalone day name
         */
        protected DateTimeFormatter createWeekDayNameFormatter() {
            return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ccccc");
        }

        // ------------- going dirty: reflective access to super

        protected String getTitleCaseWord(String str) {
            return (String) FXUtils.invokeGetMethodValue(DatePickerContent.class, this, "titleCaseWord", String.class, str);
        }

        protected int getDaysPerWeek() {
            return (int) FXUtils.invokeGetFieldValue(DatePickerContent.class, this, "daysPerWeek");
        }

        protected List<DateCell> getDayNameCells() {
            return (List<DateCell>) FXUtils.invokeGetFieldValue(DatePickerContent.class, this, "dayNameCells");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom picker skin that reflectively injects the custom content.
     */
    public static class XDatePickerSkin extends DatePickerSkin {

        public XDatePickerSkin(DatePicker control) {
            super(control);
        }

        /**
         * Overridden to reflectively inject the custom picker content.
         */
        @Override
        public Node getPopupContent() {
            DatePickerContent content = (XDatePickerContent) getDatePickerContent();
            if (!(content instanceof XDatePickerContent)) {
                content = new XDatePickerContent((DatePicker) getSkinnable());
                replaceDatePickerContent(content);
            }
            return content;
        }

        //------------- going dirty: reflective access to super

        protected DatePickerContent getDatePickerContent() {
            return (DatePickerContent) FXUtils.invokeGetFieldValue(DatePickerSkin.class, this, "datePickerContent");
        }

        protected void replaceDatePickerContent(DatePickerContent content) {
            FXUtils.invokeSetFieldValue(DatePickerSkin.class, this, "datePickerContent", content);
        }
    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.CHINA);
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(now) {

            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new XDatePickerSkin(this);
            }

        };
        // just to see some options
        List<String> patterns = List.of("c", "ccc", "cccc", "ccccc", "e", "ee", "eee", "eeee", "eeeee");
        HBox box = new HBox(10);
        patterns.forEach(p -> {
            DateTimeFormatter ccc = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(p);
            String name = ccc.withLocale(getLocale()).format(now);
            box.getChildren().add(new Label(name));
        });

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(picker);
        content.setBottom(box);
        return content;
    }

    protected Locale getLocale() {
        return Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 400, 200));
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(DatePickerConfig.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your sample code but I get an error saying "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private com.sun.javafx.scene.control.DatePickerContent javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin.datePickerContent accessible: module javafx.controls does not "opens javafx.scene.control.skin" to unnamed module @21ac0efe".... any idea what I'm doing wrong?